How old is the "old way" of using the pronoun они
I recently read this line in Sophia Petrovna, which was translated from Russian:
(For context Sophia Petrovna was both written and set in the late 1930s.)

Marya Ivanova entertained them with stories about the director's wife: when she referred to the director himself, she used the pronoun "they" in the old way.
Марья Ивановна развлекала их рассказами о жене директора; про самого директора она говорила, как в старое время: «они»

I am guessing that referring to the director with the third person plural pronoun "они" is a sign of respect just like using "вы" is in the second person.
When did this usage of "они" stop being common? Do people sometimes use it today like the person in the story did? How old is the "old way"?

'When did this usage of "они" stop being common?' -- It's a kind of word a lackey could've used to refer to his master. It conveys a different kind of respect. And it paints the person who uses it as rather servile and submissive. I'm not sure that usage ever was common between people of equal social status.

https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/23303/why-их-instead-of-его-in-dostoevskys-adolescent


When did this usage of "они" stop being common?


How old is the "old way"?

I can remember similar way of using 'они' only in classical literature. Maybe in some books byTolstoy or Dostoevsky. Moreover, in these books the pronoun 'они' was used by old people. I can only remember only old women in these stories. Like this one: https://api.polka.academy/storage/block/picture/391/regular_image-1e28829fd83fba6a22ac28d6f6cee78c.jpg So with this fact you can see that that it might have been used somewhere in the 17th-18th century.

Do people sometimes use it today like the person in the story did?

No. Never. It's a really old-fashioned thing. It was already old-fashioned in Tolstoy's books. Theoretically, it could be used in a literature to emphasize that a person comes from an isolated area from a very isolated community.

I would upvote if I had 15 reputation points. Thanks!

One may use it humorously these days, though.

I don't think, it was that archaic as the other answer claims. I think, it could be absolutely common throughout the 19th century and possibly, early 20th century, before the communist revolution.
It definitely indicated the lower social status of the one which uses it. It could be used by a peasant referring his/her landlord or domestic servants to refer to their master or other aristocrats.
